# Change object name in a loop and give it a position

Tags: r

I wonder if there is a way to create a1, a2, a3...a15 but giving it a position of [i,j] in a matrix (In R)

```
for(i in 1:15)
{
for(j in 1:10)
{
 assign(paste("a",i,sep="")),i)
}
}
```

For example:

```
   With i=1: `a1[1,1]=1, a1[1,2]=1`
```

In the next i=2: `a2[2,1]=2, a2=[2,2]=2`

```
        i=10: `a10[10,1]=10,a2[10,2]=10`
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `matrix(rep(1:10, each=2), byrow=TRUE, ncol=2)`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
a <- array(dim=c(4,4,2))

for(i in 1:4)
{
  a[i,i,] <- i
}

a[1,,]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# [2,]   NA   NA
# [3,]   NA   NA
# [4,]   NA   NA

a[3,,]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   NA   NA
# [2,]   NA   NA
# [3,]    3    3
# [4,]   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what you are looking for - is it a matrix containing the values you indicate? I.e.

```
m <- matrix(rep(1:10, each = 15), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 15)
rownames(m) <- paste0("a", 1:10)

> m
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
a1     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     1     1
a2     2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2     2     2     2     2
a3     3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3     3     3     3     3     3
a4     4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4     4     4     4     4     4
a5     5    5    5    5    5    5    5    5    5     5     5     5     5     5
a6     6    6    6    6    6    6    6    6    6     6     6     6     6     6
a7     7    7    7    7    7    7    7    7    7     7     7     7     7     7
a8     8    8    8    8    8    8    8    8    8     8     8     8     8     8
a9     9    9    9    9    9    9    9    9    9     9     9     9     9     9
a10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10    10    10    10    10    10
    [,15]
a1      1
a2      2
a3      3
a4      4
a5      5
a6      6
a7      7
a8      8
a9      9
a10    10
```

Or you you want each of these rows as a vector? I.e.

```
vecs <- split(rep(1:10, each = 15), rep(1:10, each = 15))
names(vecs) <- paste0("a", seq_along(vecs))
vecs[1:3]

> vecs[1:3]
$a1
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

$a2
 [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2

$a3
 [1] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

`vecs` is a **list** of the vectors you indicate, which is a better way of storing these data as you can use tools like `lapply()` to work on the set of vectors in a single operation.

Comment: Thanks Gavin...I know that the questions is not clear. But I don't want rows with a1, a1,  a15 or independent vector. I want a different matrix: a matrix a1, matrix a2,  matrix a15. My question is if I can create several matrix in a loop but giving then a value from the loop with a specific position in the different matrices.

Comment: it's still not clear I'm afraid

Comment: @user27355 Then what should be in row 2 of `a1` for example. Your question only suggests tat each `a` has a single row. How about you edit the Question to show the output you expect!